# Primary Key Ordinal Number

Tags: sql-server, primary-key

Does anyone know how to get the Ordinal_Position of the column that contains the Primary Key in an SQL Server table?

Comment: Do you mean the ordinal position of the column within the table? If you provide an example it should help clear up the question and make it easier for us to help you.

Comment: Yes that. I've updated the question. I don't really have an example, but I'll put up what I've got

Comment: Wich DBMS do you use ? It might vary in different versions

Comment: I don't have access to manage the database, I need this for a query my F# program is going to run.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Tested in SQL Server 2012. This is for a particular column:

```
SELECT 
    KU.ORDINAL_POSITION   AS ORDINAL_POSITION
FROM 
    INFORMATION_SCHEMA.TABLE_CONSTRAINTS AS TC
INNER JOIN
    INFORMATION_SCHEMA.KEY_COLUMN_USAGE AS KU ON TC.CONSTRAINT_TYPE = 'PRIMARY KEY' 
                                              AND TC.CONSTRAINT_NAME = KU.CONSTRAINT_NAME
                                              AND ku.table_name = 'YourTable'
                                              AND column_name = 'YourColumn'
```

And if you don't know column name, this gives you all columns in primary key

```
   SELECT KU.ORDINAL_POSITION AS ORDINAL_POSITION
    ,column_name AS ColumnName
FROM 
    INFORMATION_SCHEMA.TABLE_CONSTRAINTS AS TC
INNER JOIN 
    INFORMATION_SCHEMA.KEY_COLUMN_USAGE AS KU ON TC.CONSTRAINT_TYPE = 'PRIMARY KEY'
                                            AND TC.CONSTRAINT_NAME = KU.CONSTRAINT_NAME
                                            AND ku.table_name = 'yourTable'
```

Comment: Hi, so I'm using your second piece of code because my code isn't supposed to know the column names and I'm having an issue where your code is telling me that the primary key is the first column for a table but when I look at the sql code for that table I know the second column is the primary key.

Answer (score 0):

Take a look at this: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms188348.aspx

Query the columns table, and set the "TABLE_NAME" = to the table you're after to get the ordinal position.

```
SELECT ordinal_position
  FROM columns
 WHERE table_name = 'MYTABLE'
```

Comment: I hope it does as well but I won't know till monday. I'll let you know then.